# WPDB - Read and write value from / to database

Tags: php, database, wpdb

I have a custom field in `usermeta` called `vatnumber`.
If the field has a value, how do I read that specific value for user X?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<tr class="vatnumber">
    <th><?php _e( 'VAT-Number:', 'wpdb_usermeta' ); ?></th>
    <td><?php $wpdb->get_results("SELECT userid, vatnumber FROM usermeta"); ?></td>
</tr>
```

But I don't quite understand wpdb yet.
I know it is used for reading and writing from and to the database, but if I need a value for a specific user, do I have to assign the user_id to a variable?

On the same side, how do I make sure a certain field writes into the correct place in the database?

I would be glad if you could give me an example code tidbit.

**edit01:**

from what I understand, I can change it to

```
<?php $wpdb->get_user_meta($user_id, vatnumber,"); ?>
```

But does `$single = false` give me an array for all users with their respective user_ids? Because user_id in this case is a variable.

I'm sorry that I haven't used the WordPress database in a while, but how do I tell the system which user to get the info from? I would need to read the current_user ID, wouldn't I?

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered here on this site. Check out the  [`get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) functions in the Codex.

Comment: I've looked around a fair bit and haven't found an answer yet, sadly.
It always goes "read wpdb in the reference", but that doesn't necessarily explain the process of actually using it.
But sure, I'll look around once more.

Comment: You should check out the `{add,update,get,delete}_user_meta()` functions, they will make life easier so you don't have to write custom SQL queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the most efficient database method to add and query usermeta?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25453/whats-the-most-efficient-database-method-to-add-and-query-usermeta)

Comment: Thank you for the link. It really is about time I learn to use the entirety of the WordPress database. That way I don't always have to look around for the corresponding information first.

Comment: Note these are not methods of the wpdb class, just a standalone functions.  I guess the question has been downvoted because you didn't check out the Codex ;-) There should be many of examples in the Codex regarding these functions. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a valid question even if there is an easier way.

That easier way is `get_user_meta($user_id,'vatnumber',true);`

NOT `$wpdb->get_user_meta($user_id, vatnumber,'');` by the way.

Setting the `$single` flag to true is because although you *can* store multiple values in a single keyname but this is usually best avoided to avoid confusion.

Since you are getting a single value, the correct syntax for the database query would look something like this:

```
<?php 
global $wpdb; $metakey = "vatnumber";
$dbquery = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."usermeta WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_key = %s", $user_id, $metakey);
$vatnumber = $wpdb->get_var($dbquery);
?>
```

(You need to call `global $wpdb;` only once inside each function.)
Or, if you want to do it all at once:

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$vatnumber = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."usermeta WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_key = %s", $user_id, "vatnumber") );
?>
```

Note the use of $wpdb->prefix which generally will output `wp_` since the standard table name is `wp_usermeta` but the prefix can be changed and it is good practice to support this in a plugin (but may not be needed for custom coding on your own site where you know it is `wp_` anyway.)

Also note the action of $wpdb->prepare which tends to be needed these days to avoid MySQL injection attempts. The %d is replaced by the numeric value of $user_id. The %s is replaced by the string value of $meta_key.

If you do want to get ALL user_id's and corresponding meta_value's for those users with a VAT number stored, THEN you can use the get_results method to get them all, for example:

```
<?php 
global $wpdb; $metakey = "vatnumber";
$dbquery = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id,meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."usermeta WHERE meta_key = %s", $metakey);
$vatdata = $wpdb->get_results($dbquery);
foreach ($vatdata as $data) {
    echo "VAT for User ".$data->user_id.": ".$data->meta_value."<br>";
}
?>
```

More examples: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: actually in retrospect I don't think you need to use $wpdb->prepare at all as it is for preparing data to insert via $wpdb->query, but I am going to leave the code as is so that it shows how to use that too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally someone who actually explains the process and doesn't just link to a codex page.
I really appreciate it.

Comment: no problem, I think answers should be like that hey, so they are there for others future reference. ah if only the codex were so written also :-)